# 127.0.0.1 host header injection

Tags: apache, audit, web-hosting

I would like to know if this configuration is vulnerable to host header injection. I think it isn't, because it's listening on localhost, but I'm not sure.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:[% port %]>
    ServerName [% server_name %]
    DocumentRoot [% install_dir %]/html/lib
<Location / >
        SetHandler modperl
        PerlResponseHandler soft::WebAPI
</Location>
```

Is it vulnerable to something else ?